# jquery validate 'form' in undefined in ie 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

```
      showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList){
          this.defaultShowErrors();
          if(errors != '') {               

            var errorStr = '<p>Please make the following updates before continuing:</p>';
            errorStr +='<ul>';
            var tempArray  = [];
            for(i=0; i<errorList.length; i++) {                  
              tempArray .push(errorList[i]['message']);            
               $(errorList[i]['element']).addClass("error");
             }


               errorStr +='</ul><p>When done, click <strong>Next</strong></p>';                 
               $("#js_error_info").show();
             $("#js_error_info").html(errorStr);
            // $("#js_error_info").focus();
             $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#js_error_info').offset().top}, "slow");
          }else{
             form.submit();
          }

      },
```

This code is written in Jquery validate function/method.
When code call the form.submit() then it will give me Javascript error"'form' is undefined" while its working on all other browser. My form element id  is "frm_about_you_single", if i will call using $("#frm_about_you_single").submit() then it gives me "Out of Memeory error".

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code. As shown, `form` certainly is not defined :)

Comment: Have you bothered to read the documentation for the plugin yet?  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 0):

- The `form` argument is not defined within the `showErrors` callback function, so it's inexplicable that this would work in any compliant browser.
- You should **NOT** be calling `.submit()` from within any of the optional callback functions except for the `submitHandler` callback function, and *only* if/when you want to override the default behavior, which is already a `.submit()`.
- Too much code is missing from your OP to provide a complete answer, but basically, the plugin handles everything automatically for you... there is no logical reason to put `.submit()` inside the `showErrors` callback function.  This optional function is only used for one thing:  [*"A custom message display handler. Gets the map of errors as the first argument and an array of errors as the second, called in the context of the validator object."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)
- The `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid.  By default, when you leave it out of your `.validate()` options, it simply submits the form to your regular `<form>` `action` *after* the form passes validation.